# Django Querset Extract PKs

Tags: django

I have the following code.

```
queryset = Registry.objects.filter(
        epas_id__contains=uuid_obj_id
    ).values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

Based on my data, this correctly returns the following:

```
<QuerySet [UUID('d9a0977c-5bc0-4667-af24-5e95b83761d4'), UUID('b2d0f086-0a55-44cc-b1ba-3ebf598d24ae')]>
```

But what I want to do is extract just the values of pk in a list, so something like this:

```
['d9a0977c-5bc0-4667-af24-5e95b83761d4', 'b2d0f086-0a55-44cc-b1ba-3ebf598d24ae']
```

Any thoughts and help on how I can achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can work with list comprehension, and call `str(…)` on each element, like:

```
queryset = Registry.objects.filter(
    epas_id__contains=uuid_obj_id
).values_list('pk', flat=True)

result = [str(pk) for pk in queryset]
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks.  The list comprehension was the last bit I was missing.  It works thanks.